# Regex for 6 digit int that can't be sequential or repeated digits?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to get a Regex that checks to make sure that a supplied int is 6 digits and it is not sequential nor contains all repeating digits whether in ascending or descending order. I don't really care if the regex returns a match for the non-allowed numbers, or returns a match of the original number if it is allowed.

So for example all of these numbers are what I would need to not pass validation with the regex:

> - 123456
> - 654321
> - 069
> - 456789
> - 2435
> - 444444

While numbers like these would pass:

> - 044346
> - 666605
> - 042004
> - 678853

Thanks.

EDIT: Appears regex is not appropriate for this. A lot of great answers and multiple are right, so I just went with who answered first, thank you all!

Comment: A regex can help you to identify 6 digits only. To prevent repeated or consecutive digits the some regex is possible, but it would be too long: it would be much better and easier to use basic string manipulation functions.

There are 20 different cases you are trying to filter out, so the regex can be designed to exclude them.

Comment: So you're saying the int should be converted to a string before applying a regex?

Comment: You can ensure 6 digits using `[0-9]{6}`. Then you'll need to check each digit. You can also do it by dividing the number by 10 repeatedly and saving the remainders into an `int` array. It would be really easy to take the 5 differences between each consecutive pair. Discard the number if the differences are all 0's, all 1's or all -1's. You may use string functions or integer calculations - whatever you like :)

Comment: No, he's saying that you shouldn't be using a regex at all for this.  The easy regex test of "must be six characters" is trivial:  `\d{6}`  But the "all 6 digits can't be the same" isn't trivial and the only way to do the "not sequential" requirement is to enumerate all the possibilities (20).

Comment: Hmm I see, Flop could you post some code for what you mean (in the answers so I can give you rep!)

Comment: Would back referencing a named capture group not work?

Comment: this is another case of: I have a problem. I know! I'll use Regular Expressions... I now have two problems!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex may not be optimal for this, but it can be done with:

```
^
# fail if...
(?!
    # repeating numbers
    (\d) \1+ $
    |
    # sequential ascending
    (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d $
    |
    # sequential descending
    (?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
)
# match any other combinations of 6 digits
\d{6}
$
```

Use with `/x` flag or `(?x)` to preserve the readability.
You can also use the compact form (not recommended):

```
^(?!(\d)\1+$|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5}\d$|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)\d{6}$
```

Example usage ([ideone](http://ideone.com/T8vqh)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string re = @"(?x)
            ^
            # fail if...
            (?!
                # repeating numbers
                (\d) \1+ $
                |
                # sequential ascending
                (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d $
                |
                # sequential descending
                (?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
            )
            # match any other combinations of 6 digits
            \d{6}
            $
        ";

        string[] numbers = { "102", "111111", "123456", "654321", "123455", "321123", "111112" };

        foreach (var str in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str, re) ? "\tMatched" : "\tFailed");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
102
    Failed
111111
    Failed
123456
    Failed
654321
    Failed
123455
    Matched
321123
    Matched
111112
    Matched
```

Comment: So it seems as FlopCoder pointed out in the comments. Provide an alternate non-regex solution? Also what langauge is that? I am doing this in C#. I've seen that most regexes have mostly similar syntax but there can be slight differences.

Comment: @DOTang, this is a regex. It works in C#, copy paste, and use with `(?x)`.

Comment: Oh ok, I was confused by the # comments.

Comment: @DOTang, comments are ignored when using `(?x)` (`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`), eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Whitespace

Comment: Thanks, I am a total newb at regex.

Comment: @DOTang, expression had a minor problem, corrected it and added an example.

Comment: @Qtax - Thanks for this. In my case, I just needed a 7-digit, non-sequential number, and this did it for me: (?!(\d)\1+$)\d{7}$

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I don't think I got what you wanted, but following code works for your cases :)

```
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]{6}$")
                    && Regex.IsMatch(input, @"(([0-9]{1})\2+)")
                    && input.Distinct().Count() > 1;
```

After several re-reading I think I got what you want :) See the following:

```
    var isMatch = String.Join("", input.OrderBy(c => c)) != input
        &&  String.Join("", input.OrderByDescending(c => c)) != input
        && input.Distinct().Count() > 1
        && Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]{6}$");
```

Comment: i think your second regex has a problem. it's designed to ensure you don't have consecutive runs, right? but what about "013468"? that won't match...

Comment: but should it? I did not get what topic started wanted to achieve -- just made code to make his tests pass

Comment: i likes, but can't +1 anymore. if you're doing this really often, a "input.Length == 6" at the start would shortcut away some cases... also, you only really have to check if the first digit is !=0, since OP is starting with an integer already - so we can skip the regex completely!

Comment: I really like this solution the_joric and I +1'd you, but I gave the answer to another since they answered first.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid strings are so little in number that you could just do this:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string input = "124032";

        string[] invalid = { 
            "012345",
            "123456",
            // ...
            "000000",
            "111111",
            // ...
        };

        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{6}$") && !invalid.Contains(input)) {
            // ok
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep -- it's only 30 cases to list.  So, why not just use this?

Comment: And beware of new requirement when customer asks to support 7 digits :)

Comment: Not a fan of this approach because as the_joric points out, change management maintenance doesn't seem optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference as to why you should NOT do this.  Here's a regex that would satisfy your requirements -- it's a mess:

```
(?!123456)(\d)(((?!\1)\d{5})|((\d)(?!\1)\d{4})|((\d){2}(?!\1)\d{3})|((\d){3}(?!\1)\d{2})|((\d){4}(?!\1)\d))
```

where you must expand the `(?!123456)` for all 20 possible iterations of repeated digits.  (20 = 10 possible starting digits * (one ascending + one descending))

You start off with the negative lookahead preventing the 20 sequential digits scenarios, grab a single digit, and then do checks that require (via a negative lookeahead) that at least one digit must be different from the first digit.  If it passes this, it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a elegant solution but works!

```
/^[0]{6}|[1]{6}|[2]{6}|[3]{6}|[4]{6}|[5]{6}|[6]{6}|[7]{6}|[8]{6}|[9]{6}$/
```