# Check if numbers are in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox that contains a max length of `4` and if the user enters the numbers in sequence then needs to throw an error.

**Examples**: Below are a few examples which need to block:

`1234`, `4567`, `5678`, etc

And it can accept `1233`, `4568`, etc

I'm expecting this condition in Jquery or JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated

**Code**: I want to use the code in below format:

```
$.validator.addMethod('Pin', function (b) {
    var a = true;    
    a = (/^([0-9] ?){4}$/i).test(b);    
    return a
}, '');
```

We can replace the condition which is in bold.

Comment: I guess you can get some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519640/regex-for-6-digit-int-that-cant-be-sequential-or-repeated-digits or https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811296/3855179

Comment: Can you not adapt your previous question, from only 2 hours ago?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293970/check-if-numbers-are-repeating

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the following code

```
/**
* The sequential number would always be a subset to "0123456789".
* For instance, 1234, 4567, 2345, etc are all subset of "0123456789".
* To validate, this function uses 'indexOf' method present on String Object.
* you can read more about 'indexOf' at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
*/
$.validator.addMethod("Pin", function(b) {
  var numbers = "0123456789";
  //If reverse sequence is also needed to be checked
  var numbersRev = "9876543210";
  //Returns false, if the number is in sequence
  return numbers.indexOf(String(b)) === -1 && numbersRev.indexOf(String(b)) === -1;    
}, "");
```

The condition with the variable `numbersRev` is only needed if the reverse sequence validation is also required

Comment: You could also add a reversed version of this to check for 4321 etc

Comment: @Martijn thanks for pointing that out. Its a valid use case. Updated the code for handling the reverse case too

Comment: @sumit - Thanks Sumit. If possible please explain me the logic of this: return numbers.indexOf(String(b)) === -1;

Comment: @user3774781 added comments on top of the function. for return statement, `indexOf` returns `-1` if `numbers` does not contain the passed string.  But as the sequential numbers would always be subset of `0123456789`, it would always pass the starting index of match which will always be  greater than `-1`. So it returns true when there is no match and returns false if there is a match as `indexOf` would always be greater than `-1`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split the pin into individual digits, and iterate through them to ensure that there is at least one part that is not in sequential order (i.e difference of `+2` or more):

```
$.validator.addMethod("Pin", function(value, element) {
  var digits = value.split(''),
      invalid = true;

  // Iterate through pairs of values
  // As long as one comparison is not consecutive, the PIN is valid
  for(var i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i++) {
    if (parseInt(digits[i]) - parseInt(digits[i+1]) > 1) {
      invalid = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return !invalid;
}, "");
```

If you want to also accommodate for cases of descending sequences, i.e. `9876`, simply check for the **absolute difference** between one digit to another, i.e.:

```
Math.abs(parseInt(digits[i]) - parseInt(digits[i+1])) > 1
```

Proof-of-concept logic:

```js
// Test values
var values = ['1234', '1235', '4321', '5321'];

for(var v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
  var value = values[v],
      digits = value.split(''),
      invalid = true;
      
  for(var i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(parseInt(digits[i]) - parseInt(digits[i+1])) > 1) {
      invalid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  console.log('PIN: ' + value + '. Valid? ' + !invalid);
}
```

Comment: Is the absolute difference enough? I mean, in cases like 4323, absolute difference is always 1. I guess both sequence directions (up and down) should be tracked.

Comment: It fails for this value 21234

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
//with array
var numArray = [1234, 1243];
for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  checkIfSequential(numArray[i]);
}

//with string
var numberGiven = 1234;
checkIfSequential(numberGiven);


function checkIfSequential(num) {
  var newNum = num + ''
  newNum = newNum.split('');
  console.log(num + ': ' + newNum.every((num, i) => i === newNum.length - 1 || num < newNum[i + 1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get your point,
Why dont you just set the max length of the input field in the HTML itself and then bind a **keyup** event to the input box to trigger the validation ?

ex:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" onkeyup="validateMe()" id="key"/>

<script>
validateMe = function(){
 if(document.getElementById("key").value == "1234"){
    alert("yay! Key accepted!!");
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Because `keyup` doesn't validate the form.    It also doesn't stop right-click-paste.

Comment: oh, to prevent paste, you can do something like
$('#key').bind("paste",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 });

and what validation are you looking for?
if it is just regex, you could use form's inbuilt validation
Ex,
<input type="text" maxlength="4" onkeyup="validateMe()" id="key" pattern="[0-9]{4}"/>

Answer (score 0):

In order to fulfill the requirements for max length of `4` digits.
We enumerate all possible sequential digits according to the OP constraints `[1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789]`, and then check them with the `input` arguments.

```js
const sequentialDigits = (input) => {
  const allSeqNumsArr = [1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789];
  return allSeqNumsArr.filter((num) => num === input).length > 0;
};

console.log(sequentialDigits(1234));
console.log(sequentialDigits(1235));
console.log(sequentialDigits(5321));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is actually the cleanest solution:

```
const sequential = (number) => '1234567890'.includes(String(number)) || '9876543210'.includes(String(number));

$.validator.addMethod('Pin', sequential, '');
```

With this, you can check the PIN in incremental and incremental order.